# Django: Is it efficient to save queryset items in loop?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

Is it efficient to obtain a queryset, and iterate over it in a conventional loop, saving the changes to each item using `save()`? e.g.

```
for mod in mymodel.objects.all():

    # modify
    mod.name = 'new name or whatever'

    # Save
    mod.save()
```

If not, is there a better way? The docs state that calling `save()` hits the database which is why I ask. I'm a relative newbie to Django (and Python). In the real case, I will not be iterating over the entire database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not efficient, but sometimes you have to. However you can use `.update()` especially if it's the same value you want to put in, or if there's an easy way to predict them

so for your example: `MyModel.objects.all().update(name='new name')`, this won't loop over the entire table, it pretty much translates to `UPDATE my_model SET name = 'new name'`

You can do a multiple update following a filter too, ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once

Comment: Actually my example implied I want the same value in all, but actually this will not be the case. I think you have answered the question though, in my real case it is unavoidable, as I want to note for each item if an attempted action (sending an email) was successful.